# Trigger focusout on parent when child radio button loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a credit card selection area marked up like this:

```
<div id="payment1step2i" class="inputinline">
    <span class="inputlabel">Credit card type:</span><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="payment1step2i" value="Visa" />Visa</label> <label><input type="radio" name="payment1step2i" value="Mastercard" />Mastercard</label>
</div>
```

Then I am trying to trigger focusout whenever the user enters that area and leaves again, like this:

```
jQuery('div#payment1step2i').on('focusout', function(e){
    console.log('trigger checks');
});
```

At least in Firefox (which is what I am mainly testing with), if I click the `<label>` and then tab away from the `<div>`, I get a trigger.

However, if I click directly on a radio button and then tab away, I get no trigger.

Its my understanding that focusout should handle all of the child elements as well as the `<div>` itself (and the `<label>` is also a child element, too). How can I get focusout to happen when only the radio button is checked?

Comment: I also note that if I TAB to the radio button then TAB away from the radio button, I get focusout. But if I CLICK directly on a radio button then tab away, I get no focusout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `div` elements can only obtain focus through tab. And if they don't have focus to begin with, they obviously cannot lose it.

Comment: OK, if that is the case... I just added a 2nd event, "click" event on the radio button. That seems to solve it. Once you click a radio button, you can't really unclick it, and that is what I'm trying to validate (that a radio button has been checked).